# How can I fix this code segment to run AP CSP pseudocode?

Tags: python, list

I'm attending an AP CSP class and I'm trying to turn this pseudocode:

[image: pseudocode image]

into runnable Python code.

This is what I've coded:

```
words = ["song", "book", "video", "book"]
index = 1
n = len(words)

for i in range (n):
  if words[index] == "book":
    words.insert(index, "read")
    index = index + 1
  else:
    index = index + 1
    
print(words)
```

And this is the intended result:

```
["song", "read", "book", "video", "read", "book"]
```

But after running the code segment I coded, this is what I got:

```
['song', 'read', 'read', 'read', 'read', 'book', 'video', 'book']
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Remove the `else`, it's also not in the image

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should delete the "else" sentence, and pull the indentation of the below line.

like this

```
words = ["song", "book", "video", "book"]
index = 1
n = len(words)

for i in range (n):
  if words[index] == "book":
    words.insert(index, "read")
    index = index + 1
  index = index + 1

print(words)
```

Comment: Oh, it worked! Thank you so much. This is the first time I have asked a question here, and I'm honored to meet nice people like you. Also, I figured out that I need to set the index at the beginning to 0 instead of 1 for the code to work. Again, thank you so much! I really appreciate your response.